# Trying to print multiple variable under loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Here is what I tried

```
f = open('names.txt')
for people in f:
    print('{0} and {1}'.format(people, people))
```

Output:

```
john
and john

vlad 
and vlad
```

But my expected output is

```
john and john
vlad and vlad
```

What is wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: what is f? I think people might have a newline char at theme end

Comment: Presumably each item in f ends with a newline - maybe it's a file?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
people = people.rstrip()
print('{0} and {1}'.format(people, people))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try removing the newline characters:

```
f = open('names.txt')
for people in f:
    people = people.replace("\n", "")
    print('{0} and {1}'.format(people, people))
```

This way there should only be a new line on the next person in the file f.